# Implementing Proguard in Android throws error Gson

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am trying to implement Proguard for my Android project.
Am using Android Studio for doing the same. But finding lot of difficulties while implementation. Is there a good tutorial to overcome all the issues.
In the below code which I have used got an exception like cannot be cast.
Can anyone help me to get rid of this issue.

In my proguard-rules.txt I have used the below lines too. But it dint resolve my issue

```
-keep class com.google.gson.**{*;}
-dontwarn com.google.gson.**


public class Home_CityDet implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@SerializedName("key")
public String key;
@SerializedName("value")
public String value ;   
}

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to webservices.responses.Home_CityDet
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add to the progaurd configuration:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class Home_CityDet  {
*;
}
```

and the error magically disappeared

Comment: Did you try using only the -keepattributes Signature ?

Comment: sorry, don't remember!  (but I doubt it)